# How to calculate p-values in Spark's Logistic Regression?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

We are using LogisticRegressionWithSGD and would like to figure out which of our variables predict and with what significance. Some stats packages (StatsModels) return p-values for each term. A low p-value (< 0.05) indicates a meaningful addition to the model.

How can we get/calculate p-values from LogisticRegressionWithSGD model?

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: but you want to compute the p-value on what ?

Comment: the p-value for each feature tests the null hypothesis that the coefficient is equal to zero (no effect).

Comment: This belongs on  stats.stackexchange.com, don't you think @eliasah? Igor, hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test.

Comment: @zero323 i'm not sure if it's actually purely technical or theoretical. It's not clear what does the OP mean by model in this case.

Comment: @eliasah This is technical. The results of the model (logistic) can be analyzed.. for example http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.html returns p-values for each feature

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but some guidance for people coming to it late might be valuable.

LogisticRegressionWithSGD is [deprecated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD). In that version, no true set of "summary" information was provided with the model itself. If you cannot get access to an up-to-date version of pyspark, you will have to calculate the P-values for each of your features yourself. [Here is a nice intro to doing that by "hand".](https://towardsdatascience.com/inferential-statistics-series-t-test-using-numpy-2718f8f9bf2f)

If you **can** get the current version of pyspark, then you will want to use: 
`pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` 
(docs [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS))

Comment: That "by hand" link is not good, as it show how you compute p-values for normal data.